# Xcode compile error with PostgreSQL headers

Tags: xcode, postgresql

I am trying to include the following PostgreSQL headers files into my Xcode 7.2 project:

```
#import "postgres.h"
#import "pg_type.h"
#import "libpq-fe.h"
```

The app is written in Swift. I have an Objective-C bridging header. If I just import "libpq-fe.h" there are no compile errors.

When I try to import "postgres.h" and "pg_types.h" to get access to certain constants, I get an error with a PostgreSQL file: "c.h"

"Typedef redefinition with different types ('size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') vs 'long')

The previous definition is in OS X 10.11 > user/include > MacTypes.h

So there are two headers with the same definition:

PostgreSQL c.h

```
typedef size_t Size
```

OSX MacTypes.h

```
typedef long Size
```

If I comment out the definition in the PostgreSQL file then the project compiles. But I would rather not have to do that.

Does anyone know a way around this?

I read somewhere about using a 'backend header' but so far I have not been able to figure this out.

Thanks in advance.